# mp3 file keep on loading on audio tag in html5 webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

1. `<audio id="media" src="http://mp3-skulls.net/music/temp48/Hearts_Dont_Break_Round_Here_483968_www.mp3skulls.info.mp3"></audio>`. This code work fine.
2. `<source src="../../test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />`. This code make the mp3 keep loading and never fnish.
3. `<source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />`. Same situation with no.2.
4. `<source src="file:///android_asset/www/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />`. Same situation with no.2 and no.3.

Usually if the mp3 file cannot be loaded an error saying "Error loading : 'source path'/test.mp3" will came out. But this time the file keep loading and never ends.

Here some [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHfSL.png) as you can see it keep on loading like that no matter how long I waited.

Comment: How do you know that the audio keeps loading? You should show how you know too

Comment: @Super Cool Handsome Gel Boy Already added the screeshoot of it.. Forgot to place it in the first place..Sorry.. :D